# Displaying special characters

Tags: java, unicode

I am running into issues when displaying special characters on the Windows console.

I have written the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File newFile = new File("sampleInput.txt");
    File newOutFile = new File("sampleOutput.txt");

    FileReader read = new FileReader(newFile);
    FileWriter write = new FileWriter(newOutFile);
    PushbackReader reader = new PushbackReader(read);
    int c;

    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1)
    {
        write.write(c);
    }
    read.close();
    write.close();

}
```

The output file looks exactly what the input file would be containing special characters. i.e. for the contents in input file  `© Ø ŻƩ abcdefĦ`, the output file contains exactly the same contents. But when I add the line `System.out.printf("%c", (char) c)`, the contents on the console are:`ÿþ©`(containing more characters but I am not able to copy paste here). I did read that the issue might be with the Windows console character set, but not able to figure out the fix for it.

Considering the output medium can be anything in future, I do not want to run into issues with Unicode character display for any type of `out` stream.

Can anyone please help me understand the issue and how can I fix the same ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Reader` and `Writer` will use the platform default charset for transforming characters to bytes. In your environment that's apparently not an Unicode compatible charset like UTF-8.

You need [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) wherein you can explicitly specify the charset.

```
Reader read = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(newFile), "UTF-8"));
Writer write = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(newOutFile), "UTF-8"));
// ...
```

Also, the console needs to be configured to use UTF-8 to display the characters. In for example Eclipse you can do that by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*.

In the command prompt console it's not possible to display those characters due to lack of a font supporting those characters. You'd like to head to a Swing-like UI console approach.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, but making your changes messed up my contents to the output file written to as well. I changed the characterset in Eclipse and still the contents are not being displayed as same in the input file. What am I missing?

Comment: Then the original file was apparently not saved in UTF-8.

Comment: Well I had done that before. Perhaps, that is why it showed be exactly the same contents without messing it up.

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct. The input file was in Unicode format and not UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 is a *kind* of unicode format. Do you mean that the input file was saved as UTF-16?

Comment: @ObscureRobot: In Windows Notepad, the save option only showed Encoding to be "Unicode". I am not sure if that is UTF-16

Comment: @BaluC: I am again running into issues on Linux machine. Is there something more that needs to be done for different platforms?

Comment: On Notepad, it's the *last* encoding option of the *Save As* dialogue, all the way at the bottom (at least, this is true for XP, Vista and 7). As to the Linux problem, perhaps because it's still not UTF-8 at all?

Comment: The encoding that Windows (completely misleadingly) calls "Unicode" is indeed UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of FileWriter try using OutputStreamWriter and specify the encoding of the output.